# dropdown menu for a button in android

Tags: android

Is it possible to get a drow down view on click of a button? 
some thig like the one showed in the image.
please help[image]

Comment: Yes It is possible by using dialog and setting orientation of dialog .

Comment: see this link  http://www.google.co.in/#hl=en&sa=X&ei=tjoZT-G9M87nrAeTrrHmDQ&ved=0CB0QvwUoAQ&q=custom+dialog+android&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=a21e737f280c5c3b&biw=1280&bih=817

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make your own layout using custom baloon image and icons, make baloon image as nine patch, and use it as background, and add menus...
Don't think to use the android's menu, just make new one.